Discretisation of Heston SV with Jumps (SVJ - Bates)
I want to simulate a price path of SVJ model (Bates) in Excel to see how it works in real time but I need help on how to discretise and construct the jump part with a Poisson process into Heston model (would like to discretise the $S_{t+\Delta t}$ instead of $\Delta\ln S_t$ as I believe it is 'unadultered' without the log transform). I'm not a mathematical wiz to understand fully what I've read in papers here, here and from our very own SE Quant question Discretizing Bates SVJ Model to simulate paths wrt SVJ models hence why I'm here (again).
However, I've successfully implemented an Euler Monte Carlo simulation on Heston SV with discretised equations as follows:
\begin{eqnarray}
S_{t+\Delta t} = S_t \exp \left( \left(\mu - \frac{1}{2} v_t^{+} \right) \Delta t + \sqrt{v_t^{+} \Delta t}* \left( \rho Z_V + \sqrt{1-\rho^2}Z_2 \right) \right)
\end{eqnarray}
We denote also that $S_{t+\Delta t} = S_t^-$ where $S_t^-$ is a preliminary value of the price process before multiplying the Poisson jump process to get the final price based on SVJ model.
While the fully truncated scheme of variance process is:
\begin{eqnarray}
\ v_{t+\Delta t} &=& \ v_t + \kappa (\theta - \ v_t^{+}) \Delta t + \sigma \sqrt{\ v_t^{+} \Delta t} Z_V,
\end{eqnarray}
My question now is how to include a jump component of a Poisson process as described by Bates (1993). Basically an A-Z of the whole Poisson process of the jump component. What I understand so far, and please correct me if I'm wrong/inaccurate, is: 

A term $JdN_t$ is added to the price process equation where,
$N_t$ is a Poisson count process with intensity (or mean(?) number of events in time interval $\Delta t$ or for the whole time $T$ as in my case) that can either take a value of $0$ (no jumps) with probability $1-\lambda dt$ or $1$ (existence of jump(s)) with probability $\lambda dt$.
There can only ever be one jump for any time increment $\Delta t$ towards $T$.
$J$ being the jump size sampled from a lognormal distribution where $J\geq -1$ to avoid jumps below the origin in the price process.

What I do not understand and need help with answering are:

Why do we need to add an additional term into the drift in $\Delta\ln S_t$ namely $(r - \lambda \bar k - \frac{1}{2} v_t^{+})$, pg. 20 in this paper? Does this only apply if we use log-Euler discretisation?
How to draw a random Poisson variable for interval $(t+\Delta t)$? For example, if $\lambda = 5$ and $\Delta t = 0.1$ then probability of a jump occurring in the small time increment would be $50 \text{%}$, hence I need to draw a i.i.d random variable from =rand() in Excel and if the random draw is $\leq 50 \text{%} $ then there would be a jump, $N_t=1$? Is this correct?
What about the simulation of $J$? How do I sample it from a lognormal distribution?
After simulating $J$, would it make sense to multiply it with the preliminary price process value such that $S_t^+=S_t^-J$ where $S_t^+$ is the final price value with jump (if present)?

I have quite a few more questions in mind but couldn't pen it down here for now but will update the question if I remember any.
